# count result output don't show if result is zero

Tags: mysql

Count multiple column using the following query:

```
select count(price) as a ,count(buy_price) as b from table where c=1
```

if a or b one of result are zero then that column don't show. suppose count(price) as a output is 0 and count(buy_price) as b is 10 then output will be:

```
b
10
```

Comment: Why would you want to endure the headache of not knowing how many columns a query would return? Just return both values and deal with the 0 on the application side.

Comment: not sure if this has anything to do with your issue, but your projection is missing a comma between "count(price) as a" and "count(buy_price) as b"

Comment: I think you misunderstood what I meant - I will post an answer momentarily.

Comment: @salma Can you clarify what you're looking for? I initially thought that you were getting only one column back when you wanted two, but Joe's comment on my answer has me wondering if I've misunderstood your question. He says that you're getting two columns back currently but only want to get one back if one of the columns has COUNT(...) = 0.

Comment: Joe Stefanelli  have understand my question. There are any way to check count(..)=0 for individually. suppose check count(price) zero or not and count(buy_price) zero or not

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, your query should look like this:

```
select count(price) as a, count(buy_price) as b from table where c=1
```

Note the comma (",") between `...as a` and `count(buy_price)...`.

In general, you should have commas separating the fields in your projection, e.g.:

```
select field1, field2, field3 from myTable
```

If you really want both fields to appear in your result set, you'll need to use the built-in IFNULL function:

```
select COUNT(IF(price=0,1,price)) as a, COUNT(IF(buy_price=0,1,buy_price)) as b from table where c=1
```

Comment: COUNT should never return a NULL value.

Comment: You're absolutely right... I'm updating now. Shame how I go to SQL Server for a couple years and forget everything I ever knew about MySQL!

Comment: The same is true in SQL Server. COUNT will not return NULL there either.

Comment: I'm sure it is... I haven't really had the need to perform such a check with COUNT so I suppose I was just guessing at it. Either way my answer should be fixed now.

Comment: I think you're new answer still misses the mark. You'd probably want `IF(price=0,NULL,price)` as COUNT will not count NULL values. But OP's original request is to suppress the return of the entire column if the total count is 0. In other words, if both counts are non-zero, he wants the query to return two columns. If either count is zero, he wants the query to only return one column.

Comment: oh, I may have misunderstood OP's question. My assumption was that the column was not being returned and OP would like it to be returned with 0 as the value.